# SQLite Database Copy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, ios5

> Is it is necessary to copy my local Database.sqlite to Documents directory in ios environment?
>    If Yes .,then please explain or refer link..

Comment: `ios environment?` You should add `.sqlite` to your project, and make code to `copy` that into your `NSDocumentDirectory`. [Here's a good example of it.](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)

Comment: Is it you or someone else asking this question? If it's you, then why did you put the entire text in a quote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy it because if you put it on your app main bundle, it will be readOnly, and that's not what you want. So you must copy your .sqlite in Documents directory, or whatever directory where you have write permission.