# Very large sqlite database copy

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I see from this question ( [SQLite Database Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909307/sqlite-database-copy) ) that one must copy the sqlite database from the bundle to the working directory on installation for it to not be read-only.  But what if the database is huge?  I don't want it to take up twice the space it should.  Is there a way to delete the original from the bundle?  Any other workaround to avoid wasting so much space with a large db in the bundle that is never used after installation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How big is *very large*?

And you can't modify the bundle in any way whatsoever, including deleting / renaming / modifying files etc.

If you want to modify your db you will have to copy it out of the bundle.

However, Apple have got a solution for low space. If you can recreate the data, you should copy your db into the caches folder, not the documents folder. That way it won't get pushed into the cloud and if the device is low on space, it can be cleaned out automagically by ios.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to delete a file from the application bundle resources directory (read only).
If your DB is too large to be copied I suggest to download the database when the application start for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a database programmatically using sql statements upon installation instead of embedding a sqlite database in a bundle.